# Filter patterns in Analytics - Is this proper?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

so I am going through the filters in my company's analytics and they have about 18 individual filters for certain spam referrals. These are all Custom > Exclude > Referral

`1. sexyali.com|chinese-amezon.com
2. o-o-8-o-o.com
3. copyrightclaims.org
4. с.новым.годом .рф
5. traffic2cash.org | traffic2cash.xyz | traffic2cash.net
6. top1-seo-service.com
7. share-buttons.xyz
8. traffic-cash.xyz
9. китай.с.новым.годом.рф
10. uptime.com
11. facebook-mobile.xyz
12. slow-website.xyz
13. vitally | vitaly
14. scanner-fred.top
15. arendovalka | begalka | beslimitko | xyz`

I want to condense it down, so I made this filter, and I just want to know if that is the correct way to do it? Or if there is a better way to do it..

```
sexyali\.com|chinese-amezon\.com|o-o-8-o-o|copyrightclaims|traffic2cash|top1-seo-service|share-buttons|traffic-cash|uptime|facebook-mobile\.xyz|slow-website|vitally|vitaly|scanner-fred|arendovalka|begalka|beslimitko
```

and

```
с\.новым\.годом\.рф|китай\.с\.новым\.годом\.рф
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you read this great guide, http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam, on how to combat spam and ghost traffic. Second, you can probably optimise your regex by combining the `.com` and `.xyz`, etc.

So something like `(dom1|dom2|dom3)\.com|(dom4|dom5|dom6)\.xyz`. This will help you save some characters.